# Allow a moderator to suspend a user's privilege on a per-privilege basis

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, moderator-tools, privileges, account-suspension

I propose that moderators will have the ability to suspend a user's privilege on a per-privilege basis.

So for example, a user that abuses suggesting edits can be blocked from that for a period of time, but all other privileges he has (above or below) are still kept.

That's good for:

- Reviewing, we already have review bans, but this proposal is more general.
- Closing, users who abuse their close privileges by cluttering the review queue needlessly, voting to close old questions needlessly, closing good answers, etc.
- Suggested editing, obvious.
- Editing, obvious.
- Flagging.

Basically, any privilege that might get abused, should be blockable by a moderator or in some case by the system if certain conditions are met.

By implementing it as a general ability to suspend privileges, you gain a nice future-proofing for new privileges or changes in privileges.

Comment: If the abuse of any of those things is so bad as to warrant this, I really don't have a problem suspending the account.  Such people are unlikely to be positive contributors elsewhere, and it helps to convey the magnitude of abusing the system.

Comment: @Servy: Account suspensions are not permanent. And sometimes, you don't want a nuclear suspension. Currently the only tool we have in our toolbox is a hammer, but not all problems are nails.

Comment: @AJHenderson: It's true that it isn't needed for all privileges. But from a practical perspective, I think it's easier implementing the ability to shut down *a privilege* then implementing the ability to shut down *this, that and those privileges*.

Comment: We *already* have systems in place for most of these.  As you mentioned, users can end up edit banned, review banned, flag banned, etc.  If they're being so abusive as to subvert those mechanisms, this generally isn't just some small little thing.  This is a systematic, serious abuse, that would *warrant* a serious consequence, namely a full suspension.